# Issue with taking out a segment of an character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, structure

I have a source.txt file here:
https://palomar.blackboard.com/bbcswebdav/pid-1168887-dt-content-rid-3710280_1/courses/2177-70219/payfile%281%29.txt

```
void readData() { // Scans each line from the .txt and puts each line into an element in the array
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("info.txt", "r");

    char Line[100];
    int i = 0;

    while (!feof(fp)) {

        char agetemp[3];
        char tenuretemp[2];
        char salarytemp[7];

        fgets(Line, 100, fp);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].first, 0, 6);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].initial, 8, 9);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].last, 10, 18);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].street, 20, 35);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].city, 37, 46);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].state, 49, 50);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].zip, 52, 56);
        strsub(Line, employee[i].sex, 61, 61);

        strsub(Line, agetemp, 58, 59);
        employee[i].age = atoi(agetemp); // converted the age column to an int

        strsub(Line, tenuretemp, 63, 63);
        employee[i].tenure = atoi(tenuretemp); // converted tenure column to an int

        strsub(Line, salarytemp, 65, 70);
        employee[i].salary = atof(salarytemp); // converted the salary column to float

        i++;
    }
}
```

And my assignment is giving me a user-made function, called strsub, which is defined here:

```
void strsub(char buf[], char sub[], int start, int end) { // function template for strsub
    int i, j;

    for (j = 0, i = start; i <= end; i++, j++) {
        sub[j] = buf[i];
    }
    sub[j] = '\0';
}
```

So basically when I scan the source .txt file the strsub function is singling out particular segments and putting them into it's respective array of structure. It works fine for the most part, for example when I print out `employee[2].city`:

https://prnt.sc/hl25n7

Nothing is wrong there. However, when I try to print out the `employee[i].first` variable, it clumps together a bunch of letters, more than what I told it to do, and I don't know why. Here's a picture of when I try to print out `employee[2].first`:

https://prnt.sc/hl26gt

In the `readData()`, I only told it to go from 0 to 6, why is it taking in more input than what I told it do rather than just the first 7 characters?

Oh, and also this is my structure right here; I put it in a separate header file:

```
struct info {
    char first[7];
    char initial[1];
    char last[9];
    char street[16];
    char city[11];
    char state[2];
    char zip[5];
    int age;
    char sex[1];
    int tenure;
    double salary;
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the program isn't doing anything that you didn't tell it to do.

Answer (score 1):

We need to see the record structure of employee.  If first is defined as char[7] then it does not have enough memory to hold 0-6 (which is 7 char) + null termination.  Also, if initial is 1 char, your function is coping 2 char if input is 8, 9.

Comment: THank you! This fixed the issue. However, is there any explanation as to why would it take a bunch more than what I originally told it to just because the char[7] was too small?

Comment: The first call copy 7 char then the null would go into the next field "initial". 
 The same would happen when you copy "initial" and "last".  Essentially, you destroy the null after each successive copy.

Comment: I hope you are looking into all the arrays in the structure. All places you are copying 1 or 2 extra bytes. for example zip is of size 5. but in function strsub you copy 5 character + null.

Comment: RIght. Yeah I didn't take into account the null terminator, but I fixed it. It just threw me off because in the instructions of my project it said to make a variable "of 7 characters maximum" so my instinct was to make an array[7], without taking into account the null terminator.